# Is it bad practice to store the hash function used as part of the hashed password?

Tags: php, mysql, hash, passwords, salt

Using the [php source code](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode) for hashing+salting at crackstation.net, the returned hash includes what hashing algorithm was used. I store the hash as returned from the create_hash function in my database. Is it bad practice to store this information? Will this give a hacker an advantage?

Comment: given that the php hash functions support multiple hashes, you MUST include the hash used to be able to verify the hashed values again later. Hash types are generally easily identifiable anyways by their string lengths (e.g. md5 is 32 characters, sha1 is 40, etc...).

Comment: If you're using a good hash, it shouldn't. (Assuming one-way functions exist.) The definition of a one-way  function includes a statement that's something like: given the original function and the output, it is hard to retrieve the input. But make sure you're using a hash that hasn't been broken! Marc B brings up a good point -- you need to know anyway. Some would argue that the entire point of using hashes is that you can share the algorithm indiscriminately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is good practice. It means that if you upgrade your hashing function (to something more secure) new users will use the one new one immediately.

Now, you can't rehash users on the old hashing functions immediately, since you need their password to do that, and you can't retrieve it from its hashed state. Instead, when such a user logs in, you use their password to store a new hashed column, and reset the hashing function against their user account.

Thus, with such a configuration, users will slowly move onto the more secure system as they log in.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it's a bad practice. The hash function can often be identified from the nature of the outputted hash (e.g. string length, etc.) so you probably wouldn't be telling an attacker anything they couldn't figure out from the hash anyways.